# Reading a csv and looking for strings till it finds a column that is blank

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I have a problem that I can't solve and would like some help.
I have a csv file that I need to read in all names in column[1] till it finds a blank, then output that information to a designated csv file with the name of the entry appended to the filename. The format of the csv is: `(10-24-17, john)`. So far i have the following:

```
import csv
with open("data.csv") as input:
    for row in csv.reader(input):
        data.append((row[0],row[1]))

    for time, names in data: # I don't think this is the right way of doing things
        do(stuff)
```

Comment: yes, `for time, names in data` will work, but why doing 2 loops? just break when `row[1]` is empty. or I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: I'm going to add another dataset to this program and add more data in the data.csv in the future so that's why i'm doing 2 loops. I just need the program iterate through all the values in row[1] till it's empty

Comment: okay, so in the first loop you'll read all columns, not only the 2 current ones right? Finally, you don't even need csv in your [mcve] since your problem start _after_ having read the csv file right?

Comment: Yes you are correct in both accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand where you're having a problem.. The only code missing was the truth test on the `name` and a `break`:

```
import csv

with open("data.csv") as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i, (time, name) in enumerate(csv_reader):
        name = name.strip()
        if not name:
            print "missing name on line %s" % (i)
            break
    # ...
```

Comment: The problem lies in that part where i have to search all of row[1] (which by your answer looks correct) but also getting all the users and and execute a function to do addition of values in the following columns after row[1]

Comment: Another thing i wasn't sure of. If i wanted to go through all the columns till it hits an empty field, how would i go about exporting the data from each column to a csv with it's own name. For example: row[1] has john in the field so i want to export johns data to a separate csv named john_sum.csv